# Optimising MySQL table for aggregate queries ( 14 columns and half a million entries added each day )

Tags: mysql

Using Mysql 5.7

We are building a click tracking platform, where we record

```
CREATE TABLE `click`
(
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ref_id` VARCHAR(500),
    `datetime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    `offer_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `publisher_id` INTEGER,
    `advertiser_id` INTEGER,
    `adid` VARCHAR(50),
    `app_name` VARCHAR(80),
    `sub_pub` VARCHAR(225),
    `custom1` VARCHAR(225),
    `custom2` VARCHAR(225),
    `country_id` INTEGER,
    `os_id` INTEGER,
    `detected_user_agent` VARCHAR(1000),
    `detected_device_ip` VARCHAR(25),
    `detected_referrer` VARCHAR(1000),
    `raw_info` VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `click_fi_273355` (`offer_id`),
    INDEX `click_fi_35872e` (`publisher_id`),
    INDEX `click_fi_d78542` (`advertiser_id`),
    INDEX `click_fi_6a2e9f` (`country_id`),
    INDEX `click_fi_e2bd35` (`os_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `click_fk_273355`
        FOREIGN KEY (`offer_id`)
        REFERENCES `offer` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `click_fk_35872e`
        FOREIGN KEY (`publisher_id`)
        REFERENCES `publisher` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `click_fk_d78542`
        FOREIGN KEY (`advertiser_id`)
        REFERENCES `advertiser` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `click_fk_6a2e9f`
        FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`)
        REFERENCES `country` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `click_fk_e2bd35`
        FOREIGN KEY (`os_id`)
        REFERENCES `operating_system` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

And every time there is an install I save all the columns from **click table** to **install table** with some extra columns.
the redundancy is because I will be deleting old click granular data every two weeks but I need the granular data of clicks for which there is an install.

```
CREATE TABLE `install`
(
    `click_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `click_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `income` FLOAT(6,2) NOT NULL,
    `payout` FLOAT(6,2) NOT NULL,
    `transaction_sum` FLOAT(6,2),
    `type` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    `ref_id` VARCHAR(500),
    `offer_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `publisher_id` INTEGER,
    `advertiser_id` INTEGER,
    `adid` VARCHAR(50),
    `app_name` VARCHAR(80),
    `sub_pub` VARCHAR(225),
    `custom1` VARCHAR(225),
    `custom2` VARCHAR(225),
    `country_id` INTEGER,
    `os_id` INTEGER,
    `detected_user_agent` VARCHAR(1000),
    `detected_device_ip` VARCHAR(25),
    `detected_referrer` VARCHAR(1000),
    `raw_info` VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`click_id`),
    INDEX `install_fi_273355` (`offer_id`),
    INDEX `install_fi_35872e` (`publisher_id`),
    INDEX `install_fi_d78542` (`advertiser_id`),
    INDEX `install_fi_6a2e9f` (`country_id`),
    INDEX `install_fi_e2bd35` (`os_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `install_fk_273355`
        FOREIGN KEY (`offer_id`)
        REFERENCES `offer` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `install_fk_35872e`
        FOREIGN KEY (`publisher_id`)
        REFERENCES `publisher` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `install_fk_d78542`
        FOREIGN KEY (`advertiser_id`)
        REFERENCES `advertiser` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `install_fk_6a2e9f`
        FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`)
        REFERENCES `country` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `install_fk_e2bd35`
        FOREIGN KEY (`os_id`)
        REFERENCES `operating_system` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

1: We are getting around 40 million clicks per day which results to 40 million new rows added to the click table each day and around 5000 rows in install table.

2: I have to generate an aggregated report for the users in the dashboard with filters and grouping for date and "*_id" columns.

example 1:

```
SELECT DATE(datetime) AS item, COUNT(click.clickid) AS clicks, COUNT(install.clickid) AS installs, SUM(install.income) AS income, SUM(install.payout) AS payout WHERE datetime > '2018-05-08' AND datetime < '2018-05-17' GROUP BY item LIMIT 25;
```

example 2:

```
SELECT offer_id AS item, COUNT(click.clickid) AS clicks, COUNT(install.clickid) AS installs, SUM(install.income) AS income, SUM(install.payout) AS payout WHERE publisher_id IN (123,456,78) AND datetime > '2018-05-08' AND datetime < '2018-05-17' GROUP BY item LIMIT 25;
```

Queries like this to the click table is obviously(or so i think) is not a good idea. so i created a summery table to pre-aggregate the data which aggregates for date and hour.

The data for this table comes from click table and install table.

```
CREATE TABLE `stats_main`
(
    `datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `offer_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `publisher_id` INTEGER,
    `advertiser_id` INTEGER,
    `country_id` INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
    `os_id` INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
    `sub_pub` VARCHAR(225) DEFAULT 'empty',
    `clicks` INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    `approved` INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    `approved_income` FLOAT(6,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
    `over_capped` INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    `over_capped_income` FLOAT(6,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
    `internal` INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    `internal_income` FLOAT(6,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
    `payout` FLOAT(6,2) DEFAULT 0,
    INDEX `stats_main_fi_273355` (`offer_id`),
    INDEX `stats_main_fi_35872e` (`publisher_id`),
    INDEX `stats_main_fi_d78542` (`advertiser_id`),
    INDEX `stats_main_fi_6a2e9f` (`country_id`),
    INDEX `stats_main_fi_e2bd35` (`os_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `stats_main_fk_273355`
        FOREIGN KEY (`offer_id`)
        REFERENCES `offer` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `stats_main_fk_35872e`
        FOREIGN KEY (`publisher_id`)
        REFERENCES `publisher` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `stats_main_fk_d78542`
        FOREIGN KEY (`advertiser_id`)
        REFERENCES `advertiser` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `stats_main_fk_6a2e9f`
        FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`)
        REFERENCES `country` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `stats_main_fk_e2bd35`
        FOREIGN KEY (`os_id`)
        REFERENCES `operating_system` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

with this setup the entries are less but not less enough since the entries keep increasing every hour for each of the ids for example

```
datetime           |offer_id |publisher_id |country_id |os_id | s_installs   
2018-05-17 01:00:00    1         1              1           1        3
2018-05-17 01:00:00    2         1              8           2        3
2018-05-17 01:00:00    3         17             112         3        3
2018-05-17 01:00:00    4         3              6           1        3
2018-05-17 01:00:00    5         2              1           2        3
2018-05-17 01:00:00    1000      25             256         3        3
........


2018-05-17 02:00:00    1         1              1           1        3
2018-05-17 02:00:00    2         1              8           2        3
2018-05-17 02:00:00    3         17             112         3        3
2018-05-17 02:00:00    4         3              6           1        3
2018-05-17 02:00:00    5         2              1           2        3
2018-05-17 02:00:00    1000      25             256         3        3
```

Now getting an aggregated report on this new summery table is still slow
as the query time increases with the added rows.

With only 120000 rows for 2 days this query takes around 3-4 seconds.
I assume the time would keep on increasing as the entries get larger and larger with the coming dates.

```
    SELECT DATE(datetime) AS item, SUM(clicks) AS clicks, SUM(approved+over_capped+internal) AS total_installs,
    ROUND(SUM(approved_income+over_capped_income+scrubbed_income),2) AS total_income,
    SUM(over_capped) AS over_capped,
    ROUND(SUM(over_capped_income),2) AS over_capped_income,
    SUM(internal) AS internal,
    ROUND(SUM(internal_income),2) AS internal_income
    ROUND(IFNULL((SUM(approved+over_capped+internal) / SUM(clicks)) * 100, 0),3) AS cr,
    ROUND(IFNULL((SUM(approved_income+over_capped_income+internal_income) / SUM(clicks)) * 100, 0),3) AS epc,
    ROUND(SUM(approved_income+internal_income),2) AS approved_income,
    ROUND(SUM(payout),2) AS payout,
    ROUND(SUM(approved_income+scrubbed_income-payout),2) AS approved_earnings
from stats_main
     WHERE datetime > '2018-05-08' AND datetime < '2018-05-17' GROUP BY item LIMIT 25;
```

There is a compound index on stats_main table

```
ALTER TABLE `stats_main` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `unique_index`(`datetime`, `offer_id`, `publisher_id`, `advertiser_id`, `country_id`, `os_id`);
```

**My question is:**

1: Am I doing something wrong?

2: can the structure of the tables be changed to increase query performance? if yes how?

Comment: Average row length?  Current disk throughput? Does the expected response time require the electrons to travel faster than the speed of light?

Comment: You are missing a `FROM` clause on your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FLOAT(m,n)` should never be used.  Perhaps you want `DECIMAL(6,2)` for exact money?  And, is 9999.99 big enough?  I suspect it is not big enough for the summary tables?

`click` is awfully bulky for getting 40M inserts per second (5/sec).  Can some of those `VARCHARs` be normalized or eliminated?  Perhaps even normalize certain clumps of them.

If you are purging 'old' (2-week-old) data, consider `PARTITION BY RANGE(..)` with daily partitions, then `DROP PARTITION` is very fast.  (More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint )

The key test for whether a Summary table summarizes enough is the ratio or rows.  One-tenth as many summarized rows as raw rows is a good target.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the summary table.  Based on your two samples, I would expect something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Summary (
    -- Keys:
    date DATE NOT NULL,             -- from DATE(datetime)
    publisher_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    offer_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    -- Subtotals:
    clicks   MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,   -- from COUNT(*)
    installs SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    income   DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,  -- from SUM(income)
    payout   DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    -- indexes:
    PRIMARY KEY(publisher, date, offer_id)
    INDEX(date, offer_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

(I recommend picking the appropriate integer sizes everywhere; it saves a little space, thereby improving speed a little.)

A 'bug':

```
    WHERE  datetime >  '2018-05-08'
      AND  datetime <  '2018-05-17'
```

Leaves out midnight on the first day.

For a week's worth of data, I recommend this pattern:

```
    WHERE  datetime >= '2018-05-08'
      AND  datetime <  '2018-05-08' + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

(Your first example has `DATE(datetime) AS item` -- smells wrong.)

The second example becomes

```
SELECT  offer_id,
        SUM(clicks) AS clicks,
        SUM(installs) AS installs,
        SUM(income) AS income,
        SUM(payout) AS payout
    FROM Summary
    WHERE  publisher_id IN (123,456,78)
    WHERE  datetime >= '2018-05-08'
      AND  datetime <  '2018-05-08' + INTERVAL 7 DAY
    GROUP BY  offer_id
    ORDER BY something??
    LIMIT  25;
```

(Note:  A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is not meaningful.)

Your sample output shows a breakdown by hour.  That is possible.

You will probably need more than one Summary table.  The one above handles any combination of publisher_id and/or offer_id, broken down by day.

If you break down the data by hour, you will probably need fewer other parts to the `PRIMARY KEY` so as to get close to the target of '10'.

Every day (or hour) add new records in the summary tables for that day (or hour) from `stats_main`.  Or you can use IODKU as you go.  Either avoids the "120000 and growing" problem you mentioned.  (More in the link below.)

More on Summary tables: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

"save all the columns from click table to install table" -- I don't understand.  Perhaps there is another way to do whatever the purpose is?